# Weird issue while processing events coming from kinesis

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-connect

I setup amazon connect on aws and if I make a test call, it will put that call in a aws kinesis stream. I am trying to write a lambda that process this records and save them to database.
If I make a simple call (call the number - asnwer - hangup) it works just fine. However if I make a multipart call (call a number - answer - trasnfer to another number - hangup) this comes to kinesis as two separate records (CTR). 
My lambda process the CTR (Contact Trace Records) one by one. First it saves the CTR to a table called call_segments and then it query this table to see if the other part of this call is already there. If it is, it merges the data and save to a table called completed_calls, otherwise skips it.
If a call has more than on segment (if it was transfered to another number) it brings it to you as two events. 
My problem is that even though I am processing the events one after the other it seems that when the second event is processed (technically the call segment from first event is already in database), it can not see the first segment of the call.

here is my code:

```
const callRecordService = require("./call-records-service");
exports.handler = async (event) => {
await Promise.all(
    event.Records.map(async (record) => {
        return processRecord(record);
    })
);
};
const processRecord = async function(record)        {
    try{
        const payloadStr = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, "base64").toString("ascii");
        let payload = JSON.parse(payloadStr);
    await     callRecordService.processCTR(payload);
}
catch(err){
    // console.error(err);
}
};
```

and here is the service file:

```
async function processCTR(ctr) {
let userId = "12"
let result = await saveCtrToContactDetails(ctr, userId);
    let paramsForCallSegments = [ctr.InstanceARN.split("instance/").pop(), ctr.ContactId]
    let currentCallSegements = await dbHelper.getAll(dbQueries.getAllCallSegmentsQuery, paramsForCallSegments)
    let completedCall = checkIfCallIsComplete(currentCallSegements);
    if (completedCall) {
        console.log('call is complete')
       let results = await saveCallToCompletedCalls(completedCall);
    }
}

//------------- Private functions --------------------
const saveCtrToContactDetails = async (ctr, userId) => {
let params = [ctr.ContactId,userId,ctr.callDuration];
let results = await dbHelper.executeQuery(dbQueries.getInsertCallDetailsRecordsQuery, params);
return results;
}

const checkIfCallIsComplete = (currentCallSegements) => {
   //This function checks if all callSegments are already in call_segments table.

}

const saveCallToCompletedCalls = async (completedCall) => {
    let contact_id = completedCall[0].contact_id;
    let user_id = completedCall[0].user_id;
    let call_duration = completedCall[0] + completedCall[1]
    completedCall.forEach(callSegment => {
        call_duration += callSegment.call_duration;
});
let params = [contact_id, user_id, call_duration];
let results = await dbHelper.executeQuery(dbQueries.getInsertToCompletedCallQuery, params);
};
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Aossey how can I deal with these events or why both events don't see the records added on database from the other event?